# Unable to set the initial conditions for a capacitor or an inductor in PSpice?

Tags: pspice

I'm new to PSpice and working on setting up my initial conditions for a capacitor and an inductor in a series RLC circuit. However, whenever I try to set up my initial conditions, the IC box is greyed out and I can't edit it.

[image]

The circuit I'm trying to implement is:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know PSpice, but in LTspice you can simply add `200u ic=0`, right next to the value. WIll that work in PSpice? If not, is there a way to add the capacitor as a SPICE directive, instead of a graphical element? Something ike this: `C1 a b 200u ic=0`.

Comment: Rish, even if it's greyed it allows to initialize by double clicking on the box.

Comment: Btw, how did you make PSpice display the parameters vertically rather than horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

If it's at all like micro-cap or LTSpice you use a dot directive and place it on the schematic like this: -

.IC V(C1) = 1 or

.IC I(L1) = 2

I set this up in microcap recently for simulating a flyback controller: -

[image]